# How can I access the loop index inside a LINQ select?

Tags: c#, linq

**This code:**

```
var customers = from cust in Customers
    group cust by new {cust.Country} into grouping
    select new
    {
        Country = grouping.Key.Country,
        Customers = grouping
    };

customers.ToList().ForEach(g => 
    Console.WriteLine("{0} has {1} customers: {2}", 
        g.Country, 
        g.Customers.Count(), 
        String.Join(", ",g.Customers.Select(x => "#. " + x.CompanyName).ToArray())
    ));

customers.Dump();
```

**yields these results:**

```
Argentina has 3 customers: #. Cactus Comidas para llevar, #. Océano Atlántico Ltda., #. Rancho grande
Austria has 2 customers: #. Ernst Handel, #. Piccolo und mehr
Belgium has 2 customers: #. Maison Dewey, #. Suprêmes délices
Brazil has 9 customers: #. Comércio Mineiro, #. Familia Arquibaldo, #. Gourmet Lanchonetes, #. Hanari Carnes, #. Que Delícia, #. Queen Cozinha, #. Ricardo Adocicados, #. Tradição Hipermercados, #. Wellington Importadora
Canada has 3 customers: #. Bottom-Dollar Markets, #. Laughing Bacchus Wine Cellars, #. Mère Paillarde
Denmark has 2 customers: #. Simons bistro, #. Vaffeljernet
...
```

**How can I replace the "#" with an index/count so that I get results like these:**

```
Argentina has 3 customers: 1. Cactus Comidas para llevar, 2. Océano Atlántico Ltda., 3. Rancho grande
...
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
customers.ToList().ForEach(g => Console.WriteLine("{0} has {1} customers: {2}",
    g.Country, 
    g.Customers.Count(), 
    string.Join(", ",
        g.Customers.Select((x, i) => i + ". " + x.CompanyName).ToArray())));
```

Comment: Very interesting, that works, where is i being incremented actually?

Comment: @Edward: Take a look at this. It explains the LINQ SELECT with a two parameter lambda. http://weblogs.asp.net/fmarguerie/archive/2008/11/10/using-the-select-linq-query-operator-with-indexes.aspx

Comment: @Edward, i is being incremented internally in the Select extension method and the new value is passed down for each value.

Answer (score 2):

Try making an int x = 0; prior to your linq statement.  Then, within, print (x++).ToString().

This will make x a closure.

Comment: Very practical, esp. in my project where I need to count from 1 and up.

Comment: @LukeH's answer is better, though, right?  You could just use `(i + 1)` instead of just `i` so be 1-based.

Comment: a better answer? Perhaps, but also visually more complex. For my non-database project, using a big linq structure with lots of `new XElement` , the `.Select` is not very handy, and the other answers are more applicable. Perhaps because of a lack of my understanding of linq ...

Answer (score 1):

you can do this in order to search for the iterator index value:

```
var customers = from cust in Customers
//Get Current Index
let currIndex = Customers.IndexOf(cust)
//You can then make use of the index in the Variable currIndex
```

Comment: It is a little bit backwards to do a search for every iteration, but for small projects this is not a problem at all. In my current project I need to make a list of mail attachments, and the number of items is very low, seldom over, say, 5

Comment: You can use the LINQ "COUNT()" method with a lambda. So you could do something like: var customerCount = Customers.Count(c => c.CountryID == {cntryID}) ;