# LINQ Select distinct on DataTable not working

Tags: c#, vb.net, linq, datatable

I have the following datatable - Let's say called `MyTable`:

```
Col1:    Col2:    Col3:    Col4:
1        abc      def      <null>
2        abc      def      ghi
1        abc      def      <null>
3        abc      def      <null>
1        abc      def      <null>
```

And I'm trying to get the distinct rows:

```
Col1:    Col2:    Col3:    Col4:
1        abc      def      <null>
2        abc      def      ghi
3        abc      def      <null>
```

I tried the following LINQ statement:

```
MyTable = (From dr As DataRow In MyTable Select dr).Distinct.CopyToDataTable
```

But it's returning the original datatable with the repeated rows back to me.

What am I doing wrong AND how can I get my desired output??

Comment: check this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3242892/select-distinct-rows-from-datatable-in-linq

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Distinct` relies on the objects all implementing `IEquatable` and/or having sensible implementations of `GetHashCode` and `Equals`.  The `DataRow` class...doesn't.  It doesn't check that the value of each column is equal in the `Equals` method, it just uses the default implementation, which is to say that it checks that the references are equal, and that's not what you want.

You can provide your own `IEqualityComparer`, since you can't change the methods in `DataRow`.

The following should work, if you provide an instance of it to to `Distinct`:

```
public class DataRowComparer : IEqualityComparer<DataRow>
{
    public bool Equals(DataRow x, DataRow y)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < x.Table.Columns.Count; i++)
        {
            if (!object.Equals(x[i], y[i]))
                return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    public int GetHashCode(DataRow obj)
    {
        unchecked
        {
            int output = 23;
            for (int i = 0; i < obj.Table.Columns.Count; i++)
            {
                output += 19 * obj[i].GetHashCode();
            }
            return output;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, @Servy - Makes sense... How could I get my desired result? I'm guessing i'm going to have to look at `ItemArray`, but can't figure out how to do it...

Comment: Adding to @Servy Answer above, you can use Distinct(DataRowComparer.Default) to get unique rows

Answer (score 2):

Try like this;

```
var distinctRows = (from DataRow dRow in MyTable.Rows
                    select new {col1=dRow["Col1"],col2=dRow["Col2"], col3=dRow["Col3"], col4=dRow["Col4"]}).Distinct();

foreach (var row in distinctRows) 
{
 //
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Soner - I found this solution online in a few places, but my example really trivialized the problem - My real datatable has about 20 columns... Is there a way to do it without having to mention each column explicitly??

Comment: @JohnBustos Hmm.. I'm not sure but check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1681715/how-can-i-access-the-loop-index-inside-a-linq-select and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1044236/nested-foreach-vs-lambda-linq-query-performancelinq-to-objects

Comment: @JohnBustos Yes, there is a way to do it without mentioning each option.  See my answer.  It should work for any datatable.

Answer (score 1):

Although @Servy's question truly was the correct way to do this - Thank you so much Servy!
I also found another solution that at least seemed cleaner:

```
    MyTable = MyTable.DefaultView.ToTable(True)
```

This allows you to ask for only distinct records, but negates by original request of doing it via LINQ - Figured I'd add it in for anyone else looking at this question in the future.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that every `DataRow` in your `DataTable` is a different object. Each is an instance.